# $\{x \in V : Tx = c\} \neq \emptyset$ if and only if $\{x \in V : Tx = c\} = v + \text{null} \ T$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

**Exercise.**

Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and $c \in W$. Prove that $\{x \in V : Tx = c\}$ is either the empty set or is a translate of $\text{null} \ T$.

---

**Source.**
Linear Algebra Done Right, Sheldon Axler, 4th edition, Exercises 3E, first part of problem 8.

---

**Notation.**

1. $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ is the set of all linear maps from $V$ to $W$.
2. $v + \text{null} \ T$ is the set $\{v + n: n \in \text{null} \ T\}$ .

---

**What I've tried.**

My strategy is to show

$$
\{x \in V : Tx = c\} \neq \emptyset \iff \{x \in V : Tx = c\} = v + \text{null} \ T
$$

I first prove the forward direction. Suppose
$$\{x \in V : Tx = c\} \neq \emptyset$$

Then $\exists \ v \in \{x \in V : Tx = c\}$ such that $Tv = c$.

Consider any $n \in \text{null} \ T$. We must have $Tn = 0$. Adding $Tn$ to both sides of $Tv = c$:

\begin{align}
Tv + Tn &= c + 0 = c \implies \\
T(v + n) &= c
\end{align}

This implies $$(v + n) \in \{x \in V : Tx = c\}$$

But $(v + n) \in v + \text{null} \ T$ by definition of $v + \text{null} \ T$.

**Question:** Am I now allowed to conclude that $\{x \in V : Tx = c\} = v + \text{null} \ T$? Or have I only shown $\{x \in V : Tx = c\} \subseteq v + \text{null} \ T$?

Comment: Please avoid title lines that consist of nothing but Mathjax. It breaks some navigational shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just proved $\{x \in V: Tx = c\} \subseteq v + \mathrm{null}~T$. But you could write instead
\begin{align}
\{x\in V: Tx=c\}&=\{x \in V: T(x-v)=0\} \\
&=\{x \in V : x-v \in \mathrm{null}~T \} \\
&= \{x\in V: x \in \mathrm{null}~T +v\}. \\
&= \mathrm{null}~T +v.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! Nice and clean proof.

Answer (score 1):

I do not agree with your strategy to show $$
\{x \in V : Tx = c\} \neq \emptyset \iff \{x \in V : Tx = c\} = v + \text{null} \ T,
$$
because the book asks to prove that
$$
\{x \in V : Tx = c\}=\emptyset \ \ \text{or} \ \ \{x \in V : Tx = c\} = v + \text{null} \ T.
$$
Since $(P\lor Q)$ and $(\lnot P\Rightarrow Q)$ are logically equivalent, we can prove that
$$
\{x \in V : Tx = c\}\neq\emptyset \ \ \implies \ \ \{x \in V : Tx = c\} = v + \text{null} \ T.
$$
In other words, we assume
$$
\{x \in V : Tx = c\}\neq\emptyset
$$
and prove that
$$\{x \in V : Tx = c\}\subseteq v + \text{null} \ T \ \ \text{and} \ \ v+\text{null} \ T\subseteq\{x \in V : Tx = c\}.$$
Let $w\in\{x \in V : Tx = c\}$ be arbitrary. Then
$$Tw=c. \ \ \ \ (*)$$
Since $\{x \in V : Tx = c\}\neq\emptyset$, then there exists $v\in\{x \in V : Tx = c\}$ such that
$$Tv=c. \ \ \ \ (**)$$
Substituting $(**)$ into $(*)$, we have $Tw=Tv$. Thus,
$$T(w-v)=0\implies w-v\in\operatorname{null}T\implies w=v+n\text{, for some $n\in\operatorname{null}T$}.$$
Therefore, $w\in v+\operatorname{null}T$, which means that $\{x \in V : Tx = c\}\subseteq v+\operatorname{null}T$.
Now, let $w\in v+\operatorname{null}T$ be arbitrary. Then there exists $n\in\operatorname{null}T$ such that
$$w=v+n\implies Tw=T(v+n)=Tv+Tn=Tv\implies Tw=c,$$
where we have used $(**)$. Therefore, $w\in\{x \in V : Tx = c\}$, which means that $v+\operatorname{null}T\subseteq\{x \in V : Tx = c\}$.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your input. Are you sure? Look at how Axler proved proposition "3.101 two translates of a subspace are equal or disjoint". He used that type of strategy.

Comment: Also, if we were indeed meant to prove instead 

$$
\{x \in V : Tx = c\}=\emptyset \ \ \text{or} \ \ \{x \in V : Tx = c\} = v + \text{null} \ T.
$$

wouldn't that be saying that both can also happen at the same time, which is impossible? ("or" usually is intended as an inclusive or).

Comment: Regarding your first comment. In the proposition 3.101 we need to prove the logical biconditional $v+U=w+U\iff (v+U)\cap(w+U)\neq\emptyset$. On the other hand, the exercise above we need to prove a logical disjunction, because " $\{x \in V : Tx = c\}$ is either the empty set or is a translate of $\text{null} \ T$ " is a *either-or* phrasing.

Comment: Regarding your second comment. I don't have an answer to your question, but don't you think that "$\{x \in V : Tx = c\}$ is either the empty set or is a translate of $\text{null} \ T$" is better translated as $P\lor Q$ than $\lnot P\Leftrightarrow Q$? Where $P$ denotes "$\{x \in V : Tx = c\}$ is the empty set" and $Q$ denotes "$\{x \in V : Tx = c\}$ is a translate of $\text{null} \ T$".

Comment: Okay, I think you're right. Thanks for walking through your reasoning.

Comment: Thank you Paul.